# connect to server script on xampp

Tags: windows, server, xampp

I have a remote Windows server 2008, and install xampp on the server.  I write a server script, and on the server, I can invoke the server script with http://localhost/fire/myfile.php

My question is: how do I invoke this script from another computer?  If the IP address of Windows server is 192.168.1.1, is the URL to invoke the script http://192.168.1.1/fire/myfile.php?
But the URL doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If your other computer is in the same network, your attempt will work. Otherwise, if it is outside of your network you cannot access your PHP-File by an internal IP-Address.

In that case you have to use your WAN Address, or you could set up a DNS on your WAN-Address and redirect all incoming requests from port 80 (or the port you want to use) to your internal IP-Address on your computer running xampp.

Comment: My other computer is in a different network.  Should the URL to invoke my server script be http://WAN address/fire/myfile.php?

Comment: Yes this is right. YOURWANADDRESS/fire/myfile.php
If you don't know your address you can check it on https://www.whatismyip.com/
But in any case you have to redirect requests on port 80 to your machine. This is done in your routers settings.

Comment: Thanks, how do I redirect requests in my routers settings?

Comment: Well I do not know what kind of router you have, so I cannot exactly tell you how to do the port forwarding. Generally 192.168.1.1 is the router's IP address. In some cases it is 192.168.0.1 and in other cases even something else, but try with these two. You should get a login screen. Log on and look for something called **"Port Forwarding"**. Otherwise if you know what router model you have, you can google it. Every router model has its own way to forward ports.